# MySQL update TRIGGER on the same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-update

i'm having some problems trying to update a field of a table after updating another column of the same table.
I know that i can't perform a trigger on the same table i'm updating, but i need find a trick to do it.

For example, my table is:

```
ParentName | Age | Update_date

John         12    2014-12-01
Eric         23    2014-4-01
Jack         32    2014-5-01
Jill         33    2014-2-01
```

after updating the `age`, i need to update `update_date`, i my real situation i can't do it directly from the updating query, because i want this rule working not depending from how i update the table.

I'm trying to do that with stored procedures but i don't know them very well.

Someone has any idea or can explain me how to do it with a tored procedure?

Comment: You can use before update trigger and if the old date is not equal to new date then set the `Update_date` as  `curdate()`

Comment: with the before_update trigger it gives me this error:

Can't update table 'parent_table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: you can change the structure of table. put CURRENT_DATE ON UPDATE in default value. whenever your row is update then its value will change by current date. in this way there are no requirement of trigger as well update query

Comment: No, i cant, cause i could change the `ParentName` of a guy from John to David, but in that case i don't want to change `update_date`

Comment: Yes you are right. this is not work only for age...

Comment: @AlbertoLancellotti no you do not need to update rather the code in before update table would be something as `if old.Age <> new.Age then set new.Update_date = curdate(); end if ;`

Comment: Great! Simple and correct, if you write this comment as an answer i'll vote it as the correct one. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger could be like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER persons_updt BEFORE UPDATE ON persons
FOR EACH ROW
  IF (NEW.age <=> OLD.age) THEN SET NEW.Update_date=current_date();
END IF//

DELIMITER ;
```

Here I'm using the [null-safe operator <=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to). Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7dd2/1).